# Changing int result `15` to `{ "result" : 15 }`

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I am creating an ASP.NET Web API that calls an addition function from a dll file and finds the sum of the numbers that user input in the URL. E.g: `http://localhost:52241/api/dlladdition/9/6` (user inputs numbers 9 and 6). The result will be `15`. I want the result to be something like `{ "result" : 15 }`. How do i achieve that?

**Here are my codes:**

**dll file**

*Mathclass.cs*

```
public static class MathClass
{
    //method for Addition
    public static int Add(int num1, int num2)
    {
        return num1 + num2;
    }
}
```

**ASP.NET Web API**

*Addition.cs*

```
using ClassLibraryDll;
public class Addition
{
    public static int num1 { get; set; }
    public static int num2 { get; set; }

    public static int sum = MathClass.Add(num1, num2);
}
```

*AdditionController.cs*

```
private Addition addition = new Addition();

public int GET(int num1, int num2)
{
    int result = ClassLibraryDll.MathClass.Add(num1, num2);
    return result;          
}
```

*WebApiConfig.cs*

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DllAdditionApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/dlladdition/{num1}/{num2}",
            defaults: new { action = "Get", controller = "DllAddition" }
        );
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.MediaTypeMappings
            .Add(new System.Net.Http.Formatting.RequestHeaderMapping("Accept","text/html",
            StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase,true,"application/json")
       );

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is what you can do. Create a new model for your return data like this

```
public class AdditionResult
{
    public int Result {get; set;}
}

public AdditionResult GET(int num1, int num2)
{
    int sum = ClassLibraryDll.MathClass.Add(num1, num2);
    var addResult = new AdditionResult();
    addResult.Result = sum;
    return addResult;          
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the result type of the controller, and then you can return an anonymous class projecting the shape you need:

```
[Route("api/dlladdition/{num1}/{num2}")]
public IHttpActionResult GET(int num1, int num2)
{
    var res = ClassLibraryDll.MathClass.Add(num1, num2);
    return Ok(new {result = res});
}
```

One other suggestion is to use the WebApi [RouteAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.routeattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) to perform tailored route mapping, rather than resorting to using the global  `config.Routes.MapHttpRoute` for the same purpose. (You've already registered `RouteAttributes` with the call to `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();`)

Comment: Sure - you shouldn't try and force a "JsonResult"  here - what we usually want in WebApi is negotiated content, e.g. the browser will ask for `text/json` and WebApi will automatically serialize the result to Json.

Answer (score 0):

Just return an object of anonymous type with `Result` property. Asp.net will format it to JSON for you:

```
public Object GET(int num1, int num2)
{
    int result = ClassLibraryDll.MathClass.Add(num1, num2);
    return new 
    {
        Result = result
    };
}
```